# Deselect Bokeh tools by default

Tags: python, bokeh

When Bokeh tools are available, one is always selected by default (normally "pan"). Is there a way to have all tools be deselected while still making them available? This way the reader is less likely to mess up the plot by accident, especially on a small mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Bokeh 0.12 or so, it is possible to [configure which tools are active](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools):

```
# configure so that no drag tools are active
plot.toolbar.active_drag = None

# configure so that Bokeh chooses what (if any) scroll tool is active
plot.toolbar.active_scroll = "auto"

# configure so that a specific PolySelect tap tool is active
plot.toolbar.active_tap = poly_select

# configure so that a sequence of specific inspect tools are active
# note: this only works for inspect tools
plot.toolbar.active_inspect = [hover_tool, crosshair_tool]
```

Comment: bigreddot, please could you complement your answer addressing BokehJS API. I've tried setting `plot.toolbar.active_drag = null, undefined, false` without sucess.
I'm using the Bokeh.Plotting API, so in my case plot is a Bokeh.Plotting.figure({...}) object.

Comment: Im not sure it's currently possible in BokehJS. AFAIK on the JS side these settings are only referred to once when everything is set up and created, so that changing them after you create a figure will have no effect. The reason it works as above from Python is that serializing and sending to BokehJS is the very last step so only the "last" value matters.

Comment: Is there an attribute to Bokeh.Plotting.figure({<some attribute>}) that does the thing?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. It might work to make a new `Toolbar` from scratch (which can be passed those values a creation) and replace the old one entirely, but I have never tried so I can't say for sure. I suppose you could also try passing in an explicit `toolbar` value (configured how you want) to `figure`.

Comment: You just saved tons of my time. Thanks, @bigreddot! :)