# Ever-growing Bokeh's embed source files

Tags: python, bokeh

Bokeh's embed source file keeps getting larger every time I make one (from Jupyter Notebook). How can I stop this?

Code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()

def my_plot(color):
    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
    p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], color=color)

    script, div = components(p)
    with open('{}.html'.format(color),'w') as f:
        f.write(script)
        f.write(div)

    show(p)     

my_plot('red')
my_plot('blue')
my_plot('green')
my_plot('cyan')
my_plot('magenta')
my_plot('yellow')
```

Results:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\TomV\Codes\misc

06/06/2016  15:43    <DIR>          ..
06/06/2016  15:27    <DIR>          .ipynb_checkpoints
06/06/2016  15:43    <DIR>          .
06/06/2016  15:39            17,684 red.html
06/06/2016  15:40            23,366 blue.html
06/06/2016  15:40            29,049 green.html
06/06/2016  15:41            34,731 cyan.html
06/06/2016  15:41            40,416 magenta.html
06/06/2016  15:41            46,100 yellow.html
06/06/2016  15:43           246,485 Bokeh_embed_test.ipynb
               7 File(s)        437,831 bytes
```

Do not read further. This is added only to appease SO's mindless robot that wants me to add detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version `0.11.1` you need to explicitly call `reset_output` in some instances:

```
from bokeh.io import reset_output

reset_output()
```

I would suggest calling this at the top of your `my_plot` function.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. By the way, I still have [another answered Bokeh question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639353/deselect-bokeh-tools-by-default) if you're interested. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI hopefully this situation can be improved in future releases, and the explicit call not needed or not needed in as many cases.